# Angularjs - Send and Recieve Data Similar to Autocomplete

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-services, angularjs-http

I am trying to write feature in my application whereby i have an input field, and upon the user typing a value, i should post the value (upon every character typed) to a service/method in my backend code... I should then expect a JSON object of matching results. For example:

If i type: **wi**

I should see the below returned:

```
willow
wind
wine
window
william
wilter
wistle
will
```

If i add an **n** to the value, e.g I should see the below returned:

```
window
```

HTML:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="serachTerm">

<li ng-repeat="data in SearchResults">
    {{ data }}
</li>
```

JS:

This is a service ive used to get data, but unsure on how to send and listen for updates on every character typed:

```
app.factory('getDataFactory', function($http) {
  return {
    getData: function(done) {
      $http.get('data.json')
      .success(function(data) {
        done(data);
      })
      .error(function(error) {
        alert('Something has broke');
      });
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at the directive created by the people over at ui bootstrap.

It is an autocomplete directive that handles the data input and sends it to the backend and renders the suggestions.

They even have working code examples for you to see how to wire the different parts up.

[Typeahead](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/typeahead)